# Multiplication of two different bit numbers in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have two numbers A and B, both of different sizes and i need to multiply them using VHDL.  I don't know the exact logic to multiply them.

Comment: But * operator doesn't work.

Comment: This is why I wrote that you should figure out which types to use ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are trying to multiply two `std_logic_vector`, then `*` will fails,
since `std_logic_vector` is just an array of `std_logic` elements, but does not
have an inherit numerical representation.

So take a look a the
[`ieee.numeric_std`](https://www.google.dk/#q=ieee.numeric_std+package) VHDL
package.  This defines `unsigned` and `signed` types that assume a typical
numerical representation of an array, along with operators on these types,
including `*`.  Using this package you can do:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
c <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b));
```

Note that for `*` the `c'length` is `a'length + b'length`.

Btw. welcome to Stack Overflow, and please spend some time in Stack Overflow
[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), so you can get better answers in
the future, and avoid being voted down or get the answer closed.

Comment: Is this synthesizable?

Comment: @ParsaNoori: Yes, at least from my FPGA experience with tools like Intel Quartus and Xilinx Vivado.